# How to pass the ID Token and Access Token from AWS as cookies and check if they are expired?

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cognito

Essentially, I want to just pass the ID Token and the Access token into a cookie so that I can access them from another url that my app links the user to after logging in and returning these tokens. After I have the ID token and the Access Token in a cookie, I want to be able to access them in the next url and then check if they have not expired. How would I go about doing this?

I can't really find documentation on this as User Pools are still in their Beta on AWS. Thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID and Access tokens are formatted as [JWT](https://jwt.io/) (JSON Web Tokens). These tokens have additional details (including expiration) embedded in their payload. You can parse payload of ID and Access tokens as a JSON string and read the token expiry timestamp. Use this timestamp to find out if the tokens are still valid.

Comment: Thanks! And is it safe practice to store these string values as cookies?